# Synonym for "Labor intensive" phrase

Tags: word-request, phrases, synonyms

Can I request for a word which can describe the following sentences;

1. Production of labor intensive products
2. Human and capital intensive products

Answer (score -1):

Just a couple of suggestions hope they help I am not quite sure what you want and how you will use it
1. laborious process or back-breaking
2. resource-intensive development or laborious and costly